# Using for loop with strings (Python)

Tags: python

I have to write a defined cycle that greets my five best friends on the screen (Using `for` loop).
I want it to be like this:

```
"Hi Lucas!"
"Hi Mark!"
"Hi Leo!"
```

I know how to use `for` with numbers but I get lost when we are talking about `strings`.

Comment: Search "Python list tutorial iteration" and you'll find many links with answers more complete than we should give here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code line:

```
names = ['Lucas', 'Mark', 'Leo']
for name in names:
    print("Hi %s!" % name)
```

Comment: That is fne, but check for te new ways for string substitution.  `%` is a bit "2000ish" - for years, `.format` has been somewhat preferred, but `%` would make sense as it was more concise. However, since Python 3.6 the f-strings should be the preferred method.

Comment: @jsbueno f string is the way I go with. Clear and concise without any noise.

Answer (score -1):

You should avoid using `range` when you already have an iterable since using range puts an overhead.

Just iterate the list and print.

```
friends = ["Lucas", "Mark", "Leo"]

for name in friends:
    print(f'Hi {name}!')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
best_friends = ["Lucas", "Mark", "Leo", "Tommy", "Jack"] #Five friends name
for friend in best_friends:
    print("Hi " + friend + "!")
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: you should avoid concatenating string. Search f strings in python.

Comment: Please do not post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.